# How to find Jframe Name

Tags: java, swing, jframe, title

I want to find the name of the opened Jframe by clicking a button in that same Jframe.

[image]

Comment: It's not a frame, it's a tab of a `JTabbedPane`.  How you would do this would depend greatly on what information you have what structure your code/UI takes

Comment: You question and your picture contradict each other, you might want to update the question or picture so they agree on what you are want to try and achieve

Comment: Thank you . I'll edit that.!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think OP means the java file that the JFrame is in.

Comment: @Sweeper Well, that's now three guess at what the OP wants (I have two) :P

Comment: @Sweeper I don't know how to explain because I'm not an English man. I want to dispose the frame when that Jframe name equals with some names I saved. There is a table named "blocked_tables" . I want to search  them by using one code. I can type the name and search. But I have to change the code for each frames separately.  Could you please give me an advise sir?

Answer (score 0):

found answer for my question. getClass()